# QPaint with mouse Event panning

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, pan

I have created a paint widget, that I want to implement a pan event with hand icon tool, which usually sees in many softwares. it is when user press on mouse button and hold it then move over within `Qpainter canvas`, the drawing follows the mouse movement. I can't find out how to do it in PyQt5.

**VISUAL EXAMPLE**

**The current screen:**

[image]

**The desired screen event:**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 1200, 600))        
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.sizeHint()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self._width = 350
        self._height = 250

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.cyan))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkCyan)

        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        r.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        painter.drawRect(r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

**Update of code:**

**Visualization:**

Well,that's what happens when I implement the updated code in my central code. 
it is when user clicks and picks section from circular then plots within the widget, right after click and select another section from rectangular. The widget should update and erase previous drawing. But it does't do that. In my previous code the section drawing appears directly in the center of widget, now it sticks to upperleft edge of canvas.

[image]

**A part of code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 800, 800))

        self.button = Button()
        self.paint = Createpaintwidget()
        self.button.valuesChanged.connect(self.paint.set_size_squares)
        self.button.valueChanged.connect(self.paint.set_size_round)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.button)

class Createpaintwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sizeHint()        
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF()
        self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF()
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle
        self._factor = 1.0

        self._pos = QtCore.QPointF()
        self._initial_flag = False
        fnt = self.font() 
        fnt.setPointSize(20) 
        self.setFont(fnt) 

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not self._initial_flag:
            self._pos = self.rect().center()
            self._initial_flag = True

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int,int)
    def set_size_squares(self, w, h):
        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF(w, h)
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle
        self.updatePath()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def set_size_round(self, v):
        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF(v, v)
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse
        self.updatePath()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        painter.translate(self.rect().center())
        painter.scale(self._factor, self._factor)
        painter.translate(-self.rect().center())

        painter.translate(self._pos)
        painter.drawPath(self._path)
        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle:
            painter.fillRect(self._rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern))
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))
            painter.drawRect(self._rect)
        elif self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse:
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern))
            painter.drawEllipse(self._rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = event.pos() - self._initial_pos
        self._path.translate(delta)
        self._rect.translate(delta)
        self.update()
        self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def updatePath(self):
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        r = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(), self._size)
        r.moveCenter(QtCore.QPointF())
        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF(r)
        self._path.moveTo(QtCore.QPointF())
        p = QtCore.QPointF(self._size.width()/2 + 75 ,0)
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, -16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.moveTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, 16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.addText(p + QtCore.QPoint(16, 0) , self.font(), "x")

        self._path.moveTo(QtCore.QPointF())
        p = QtCore.QPointF(0, -self._size.height()/2 - 75)
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(16, 16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.moveTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, 16))
        self._path.addText(p + QtCore.QPoint(0, -16) , self.font(), "y")

        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle:
            pl = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            pr = r.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            self._path.moveTo(pl)
            self._path.lineTo(pr)
            for p in (pl, pr):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, -40))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, 20))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.width())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.center().x() - 0.5*fm.width(word) , r.bottom() +  100)
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)

            pt = r.topLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(-75, 0)
            pb = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(-75, 0)
            self._path.moveTo(pt)
            self._path.lineTo(pb)
            for p in (pt, pb):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(40, 0))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-20, 0))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.height())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.left() -80 - fm.width(word) , r.center().y() + 0.5*fm.height())
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)
        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse:
            pl = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            pr = r.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            self._path.moveTo(pl)
            self._path.lineTo(pr)
            for p in (pl, pr):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, -self._size.height()/2 - 20))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, 10))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.width())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.center().x() - 0.5*fm.width(word) , r.bottom() +  100)
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)
        self.update()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self._factor *= 1.01**(event.angleDelta().y()/15.0)
        self.update()
        super().wheelEvent(event)

class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    valuesChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int,int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        roundbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Round')
        squarebutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Square')
        Alay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Alay.addWidget(roundbutton)
        Alay.addWidget(squarebutton)
        self.value = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        roundbutton.clicked.connect(self.getbuttonfunc)
        squarebutton.clicked.connect(self.sqaurebuttonfunc)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def getbuttonfunc(self):
        number, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(self, self.tr("Set Number"),
                                         self.tr("Input:"), 1, 1)
        if ok:
            self.valueChanged.emit(number)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def sqaurebuttonfunc(self):
        number, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(self, self.tr("Set Number"),
                                         self.tr("Input:"), 1, 1)
        if ok:
            self.valuesChanged.emit(number, number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the pan you must follow the following steps:

- Get the initial position in mousePressEvent
- In mouseMoveEvent move the rectangle with the difference between the current position and the initial position, and update the initial position with the current position.

The implementation is as follows:

```
class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self._width = 350
        self._height = 250
        self._rect = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        self._initial_flag = False
        self._initial_pos = QtCore.QPoint()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not self._initial_flag:
            # set initial pos
            self._rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
            self._initial_flag = True
        super(Paint, self).showEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.cyan))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkCyan)
        painter.drawRect(self._rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._rect.contains(event.pos()):
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
            self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super(Paint, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._rect.contains(event.pos()):
            delta = event.pos() - self._initial_pos
            self._rect.translate(delta)
            self.update()
            self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super(Paint, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        super(Paint, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

But instead of doing it Qt already offers classes that allow you to do the tasks that you point out in a simple way, in this case it is to use QGraphicsView with the QGraphicsItem:

```
class GraphicsRectItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        super(GraphicsRectItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        super(GraphicsRectItem, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)
        rect_item = GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 350, 250)
        rect_item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.cyan))
        rect_item.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkCyan)
        rect_item.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.scene().addItem(rect_item)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self._width = 350
        self._height = 250
        self._initial_flag = False
        self._initial_pos = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._pos = QtCore.QPoint()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not self._initial_flag:
            # set initial pos
            self._pos = self.rect().center()
            self._initial_flag = True
        super(Paint, self).showEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.cyan))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.darkCyan)
        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        r.moveCenter(self._pos)
        painter.drawRect(r)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        r.moveCenter(self._pos)
        if r.contains(event.pos()):
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
            self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super(Paint, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QSize(self._width, self._height))
        r.moveCenter(self._pos)
        if r.contains(event.pos()):
            delta = event.pos() - self._initial_pos
            self._pos += delta 
            self._initial_pos = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(Paint, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        super(Paint, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

**Update:**

One way to implement the task is to have an element or set connected element, in this case it is a QPainterPath plus a QRectF, the first will draw the arrows, lines, etc. and the second the rectangle or central circle. After that, it is enough to move those elements according to the case.

```
class Createpaintwidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sizeHint()        
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF()
        self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF()
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle
        self._factor = 1.0

        self._pos = QtCore.QPointF()
        self._initial_flag = False
        fnt = self.font() 
        fnt.setPointSize(20) 
        self.setFont(fnt) 

    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not self._initial_flag:
            self._pos = self.rect().center()
            self._initial_flag = True

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def set_size_squares(self, w, h):
        self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF(w, h)
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle
        self.updatePath()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def set_size_round(self, v):
        self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self._size = QtCore.QSizeF(v, v)
        self._type = QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse
        self.updatePath()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)

        painter.translate(self.rect().center())
        painter.scale(self._factor, self._factor)
        painter.translate(-self.rect().center())

        painter.translate(self._pos)
        painter.drawPath(self._path)
        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle:
            painter.fillRect(self._rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern))
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))
            painter.drawRect(self._rect)
        elif self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse:
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern))
            painter.drawEllipse(self._rect)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = event.pos() - self._initial_pos
        self._path.translate(delta)
        self._rect.translate(delta)
        self.update()
        self._initial_pos = event.pos()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def updatePath(self):
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        r = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(), self._size)
        r.moveCenter(QtCore.QPointF())
        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF(r)
        self._path.moveTo(QtCore.QPointF())
        p = QtCore.QPointF(self._size.width()/2 + 75 ,0)
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, -16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.moveTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, 16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.addText(p + QtCore.QPoint(16, 0) , self.font(), "x")

        self._path.moveTo(QtCore.QPointF())
        p = QtCore.QPointF(0, -self._size.height()/2 - 75)
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(16, 16))
        self._path.lineTo(p)
        self._path.moveTo(p)
        self._path.lineTo(p + QtCore.QPoint(-16, 16))
        self._path.addText(p + QtCore.QPoint(0, -16) , self.font(), "y")

        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Rectangle:
            pl = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            pr = r.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            self._path.moveTo(pl)
            self._path.lineTo(pr)
            for p in (pl, pr):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, -40))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, 20))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.width())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.center().x() - 0.5*fm.width(word) , r.bottom() +  100)
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)

            pt = r.topLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(-75, 0)
            pb = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(-75, 0)
            self._path.moveTo(pt)
            self._path.lineTo(pb)
            for p in (pt, pb):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(40, 0))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-20, 0))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.height())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.left() -80 - fm.width(word) , r.center().y() + 0.5*fm.height())
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)
        if self._type == QtGui.QRegion.Ellipse:
            pl = r.bottomLeft() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            pr = r.bottomRight() + QtCore.QPointF(0, 75)
            self._path.moveTo(pl)
            self._path.lineTo(pr)
            for p in (pl, pr):
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, -self._size.height()/2 - 20))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(0, 10))
                self._path.moveTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(10, -10))
                self._path.lineTo(p+ QtCore.QPoint(-10, 10))
            word = "{}".format(self._size.width())
            p = QtCore.QPointF(r.center().x() - 0.5*fm.width(word) , r.bottom() +  100)
            self._path.addText(p , self.font(), word)
        self.update()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        self._factor *= 1.01**(event.angleDelta().y()/15.0)
        self.update()
        super().wheelEvent(event)
```

Comment: Great, you are indeed clever. Thanks. I notes when `QGraphicsView` runs and autoscrolles appears but this is not the case when `Qpainter`uses, can a scroll add to `Qpainter`?.But what is the difference between `QPainter` and `QGraphicsView`. I have seen `QGraphicsView` is been used widely?

Comment: @ZarKha QGraphicsView is a widget specialized in handling items that internally uses QPainter, that is, it is a high level way to paint. The scrollbar appears because QGraphiscView is designed to handle items that may be in larger positions on your screen, it can be disabled. In conclusion with QPainter are in the stone age where it was painted manually and with QGraphicsView you are using MS paint or similar

Comment: @ZarKha If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: My last question according to your answer, I had this code line  `self._rect = `within `def paint`, in your answer you have brought it outside of function, that indeed gives some errors which I have in my private code. The event wont run! is it a way to keep it inside the function? I really need this to be solved?

Comment: @ZarKha Surely in the old answer do not point out that the rectangle was movable so the rectangle is fixed and used in the paintEvent, but in this case is dynamic although I think it can maintain the previous logic, at a time I will give an alternative. On the other hand I do not know the implementation of your private code so I will not think since you probably have other errors.

Comment: @ZarKha Your current code is a bit dirty, I'm going to improve it and add my solution. mail is not necessary.

Comment: @ZarKha I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: I have reconstructed the problem and updated code above, please can you have a look on it. try different values for round and square.

Comment: @ZarKha to make it simple, the idea of SO is to solve problems not to implement projects, your responsibility is to provide an adequate [mcve] so that users like me take it as a base, and not change it at every moment, do not you think it is uncomfortable for us? ?, until now I have had patience and I have provided solutions for every modification you have made so it will take me time to solve and review your last modification to give you a solution, if you make another modification I will not continue to help you unfortunately since you are forcing Question.

Comment: @ZarKha Many think they can post a question on SO and think they are publishing their work, well no, if you want a quality answer you should take the time to clearly state your problem before posting your question, you should have similar pressure to which you would have to show a solution to your boss or contractor, remember that the community will help you if you are clear. We assume that you have posted your question with responsibility to the community.

Comment: @ZarKha [cont,]  So for a next occasion, take it into your mind, the time of others is also valuable. So I'll keep trying to help you with this problem but it will take me a little time.

Comment: I totally agree and feeling that my questions are now not so much simple. Introducing and clarifying of problem in a way lookers get straight to the core of problem, helping to obtain a straight forward solution. that will be a great strategy to start from.

Comment: @ZarKha The error I had in my solution was that I did not reset the QPainterPath when new dimensions or new form was established, I have already corrected it, try it again.

Comment: Now it works 100%. Thanks for your patience. Sometimes it is much easier than we think!. Great. :)